# Should I bother about user might mess up my program's files?

Tags: c++, linux

I am writing a C++ program for Linux which creates some files on the disk during the work. These files contain information about program's internal objects state, so that the next time the program is started it reads these files to resume previous session. Some of these files are also being read/written to during the execution to read/write some variables values. The problem is that modifying/renaming/deleting these files would lead in undefined behavior, segmentation faults and other surprises causing the program to crash. I am certainly not going to restrict the user in accessing files on his/her machine, but inside the program I can always check if a file has been modified before accessing it to at least prevent the program from crash. It would involve many extra checks and make the code larger though.

The question is what is a good practice to deal with such issues? Should I even be so paranoid, or just expect the user to be smart enough to not mess with program's files?

Comment: Re. `"...modifying/renaming/deleting these files would lead in undefined behavior, segmentation faults and other surprises causing the program to crash"`: that should never happen.  Bad input should *not* cause an application to crash.  You need to fix your code to verify the data it reads and take the required steps if verification fails.

Comment: In my experience, users never intentionally caused trouble. It was either hard disk getting corrupted somehow or anti-virus not 'liking' the files.

Comment: Non-malicious users rarely cause this sort of problem, but you do encounter folks who think they know better from time to time. Sometimes they do know better, just not when it comes to your program.

Comment: Bad data should never cause a crash IMO. But you should assume the users can be responsible for their files. If they edit what they don't understand they're asking for trouble!

Comment: If you want a (relatively) quick way to verify that an on-disk file hasn't been modified since you last saved it, you can generate a SHA1 (or MD5 or whatever) hash code for the file (right after you write it out) and append that to the end of the file.  Then, before you try to load the file in, pre-read the file's contents to recompute the hash code, and compare the computed hash code against the one stored at the end of the file.  If they don't match, put up an error message saying that the file has been corrupted, and don't try to load the file.

Comment: (Note that the hash code check would protect you against naive users and accidental file corruption, but a clever user could modify the file's contents and then update the hash code to match, and then the user-modified file would still pass your hash-code check.  That might be a problem only if your files are worth "cheating" on, e.g. if they contain the high scores table for a multiplayer game or something like that)

Comment: @Galik: Most games, which have several gigabytes of read-only external data (e.g. graphics and sound) do not validate all their data before using it, as this would increase the loading time of the game by several minutes. Therefore, games will probably crash if the external data is tampered with. However, I do agree that non-read-only data, such as save files created by the user, should generally be fully validated.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel There is a difference between validating data and crashing due to bad data. Code must be robust, even in games.

Comment: Thank you, guys, for the participation! After reading your answers I am considering using something like hash checking. But how much will it affect the performance of read/write operations if I need to validate many files consequently and do it quite frequently?

Comment: During runtime, you also have the option of monitoring the file through `inotify`. At startup you can verify checksums, and at runtime, monitor the files if you've got a lot of write operations.

Comment: @Alexey104 adding a hash-check is unlikely to noticeably effect the performance of read/write operations on a modern computer, unless the files are *huge* (e.g. tens of megabytes or larger), and in the case where they are huge, you can be clever and hide the additional CPU overhead of the hash-check by weaving the hash-checking in to the I/O operations you have to do anyway, so that the time the CPU spends calculating hash-values is time it otherwise have spent waiting for I/O anyway, and thus the total operation time doesn't increase much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check your resources and if it is worth the effort. Will the user be even tempted to trace and edit these files?

If so, my advice is this: Don't be concerned whether or not the file has been modified. Rather you should validate the input you get (from the file).

This may not be the most satisfying answer, but error handling is a big part of programming, especially when it comes to input validation.

Let assume you are writing into a `~/.config/yourApp/state.conf`.

- Prepare defaults.
- Does the file exist? If not use defaults.
- Use some well known structure like INI, JSON, YAML, TOML, you name it, that the user can understand and the application can check for integrity (libraries may help here). If the file is broken use defaults.
- In case the user does delete a single entry, use the default value.
- Some values deserve special checking in case a out of bound access would lead to undefined behavior. If the values is out of bounds, use a default.
- Ignore unknown fields.
- In case you can't recover from a malformed input, provide a meaningful error message, so the user may be able to restore a save state (restore from a backup or start over from the beginning).

Comment: Thank you, your post was useful for me!

Answer (score 0):

If using files are really important to your codebase then you can simply hide those files by **adding dot "." before them**. This way the user will not be able to know the files are there unless checked specifically.

If you want to access those files from anywhere in the system you can also store these files in some temp hidden folder which can be accessed easily.

```
eg: ~/.temp_proj/<file>
```

This way the folder will be hidden from the user and you can use it for your own program.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Odd. I just tried this on Windows 10 and it didn't appear to work.

Comment: @user4581301, this method(appending dot before file name to make it hidden) does not work on Windows, it is only for Unix-like systems.

Comment: @Alexey104 That was me being a troll and snarkilly suggesting that the answer doesn't even correctly answer the question it is trying to answer.

Comment: @user4581301 I had suggested this approach because in the explanation of the question it is mentioned that it is a Linux system. And also I have not given the complete solution just a way to work around if using files are really important.